# Unclear 404 get ajax error passing integer to django

Tags: python, ajax, django

Totally unclear 404 Ajax error.

```
var int_page_number = 2;
  $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/loadmore/',
        data: { 'page_number' : int_page_number},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data);          


            }
});
```

In the place passing data, I tried both using apostrophe and not around `page_number`. It's 404 so error may be in frontedn, but anyways I attach django `urls.py` string just in case :

```
 url(r'^loadmore/(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$', views.loadmore),
```

and views.py function, which is all right:

```
@api_view(['GET', ]) 
def loadmore(request,page_number):
    answers_to_questions_objects = Question.objects.filter(whom=request.user.profile).filter(answered=True).order_by('-answered_date')
    paginator = Paginator(answers_to_questions_objects,10)
    current_page = (paginator.page_number)
    answers = serializers.serialize('json', current_page)
    data = {
        'answers': answers

    }
    return Response(data)`
```

Answer (score 0):

For your url you should make a call to the url like `/loadmore/2/`, but you make the call like `/loadmore/?page_number=2`. So your ajax should be like this:

```
var int_page_number = 2;
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '/loadmore/' + int_page_number + '/',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);  
    }
});
```